# <a> tag is not clickable and not linked

Tags: html, django

Okay , I am not sure if that is a problem with my Django project logic or with my html tags , so here it goes

I am trying to make a link that lists all the groups created by a specific user

the template code

```
    <h1>
        <a href"{% url 'infrastructure:user-orgs-view' slug=request.user.slug%}"> Your Organizations </a>
    </h1>
```

url.py part

```
path('accounts/<slug>/orgs', views.UserOrgsView, name='user-orgs-view' )
```

my view

```
def UserOrgsView(request, slug):
    orgs = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug).organization_set
    return render(request, 'user_orgs.html', { 'orgs' : orgs})
```

the only css I am using on this page

```
    body {
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    p *{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

what happens is the tag appears as normal text , not clickable .. not linked .. nothing .. any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: You forgot an `=` between `href` and `{% ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```html
<a href="{% url 'infrastructure:user-orgs-view' slug=request.user.slug%}"> Your Organizations </a>
```